# H265 Supported Hardware

Tags: linux, codec, hevc

How do I know if underlying hardware supports H.264 or H.265 ?
I want to play H.264/H.265 video by hardware encoding only.

I am using Ubuntu-19.04 now.

Comment: Point your browser to https://www.youtube.com/html5 (that's not a video; it's a test page -- if the middle column labelled H.264 is blue-checked on that page, then your hardware/software supports it)

Comment: Thanks. But it only answers H.264 and not for H.265. How can I get this information through command line ?